# Hash with array as key

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm defining a hash with an array as a key and another array as its value. For example:

```
for_example = {[0,1] => [:a, :b, :c]}
```

Everything is as expected below.

```
my_hash = Hash.new([])
an_array_as_key = [4,2]
my_hash[an_array_as_key]                #=> []
my_hash[an_array_as_key] << "the"       #=> ["the"]
my_hash[an_array_as_key] << "universal" #=> ["the", "universal"]
my_hash[an_array_as_key] << "answer"    #=> ["the", "universal", "answer"]
```

But if I try to access the keys:

```
my_hash                           #=> {}
my_hash.keys                      #=> []
my_hash.count                     #=> 0
my_hash.values                    #=> []
my_hash.fetch(an_array_as_key)    # KeyError: key not found: [4, 2]
my_hash.has_key?(an_array_as_key) #=> false
```

Rehash doesn't help:

```
my_hash        #=> {}
my_hash.rehash #=> {}
my_hash.keys   #=> []
```

But the values are saved:

```
my_hash[an_array_as_key] #=> ["the", "universal", "answer"]
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand this, You need to understand the difference between `Hash::new` and `Hash::new(ob)`. Suppose you define a `hash` object using `Hash::new` or hash literal `{}`. Now whenever you will write a code `hsh[any_key]`, there is two kind of output may be seen, if `any_key` don't exist, then **default** value `nil` will be returned,otherwise whatever value is associated with the key will be returned. The same explanation will be applicable if you create any `Hash` object using `Hash.new`.

Now `Hash.new(ob)` is same as `Hash.new`, with one difference is, you can set any default value you want, for non existent keys of that hash object.

```
my_hash = Hash.new([])
my_hash[2] # => []
my_hash[2].object_id # => 83664630
my_hash[4] # => []
my_hash[4].object_id # => 83664630
my_hash[3] << 4 # => [4]
my_hash[3] # => [4]
my_hash[3].object_id # => 83664630
my_hash[5] << 8 # => [4, 8]
my_hash[5] # => [4, 8]
my_hash[5].object_id # => 83664630
```

Now see in the above example `my_hash` has no keys like `2`,`3` and `4`. But the `object_id` proved that, all key access results in to return the same array object. `my_hash[2]` is not adding the key to the hash `my_hash`, rather trying to access the value of the key `2` if that key exist, otherwise it is returning the default value of `my_hash`. Remember all lines like `my_hash[2]`,`my_hash[3]` etc is nothing but a call to [`Hash#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) method.

But there is a *third* way to go, may be you are looking for, which is `Hash::new {|hash, key| block }`.With this style you can add key to the hash object if that key doesn't exist, ***with a default value of same class instance,but not the same instance.***, while you are doing actually [`Hash#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) method call.

```
my_hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = []}
my_hash[2] # => []
my_hash[2].object_id # => 76312700
my_hash[3] # => []
my_hash[3].object_id # => 76312060
my_hash.keys # => [2, 3]
```

Comment: @zeroed, with Arup's last approach, how would you check to see if `my_hash` had a particular key? In other situations you might write `if my_hash(:cat)...`, but here that would always evaluate `true`, because the if statement would add `:cat` to the hash (`my_hash => {2=>[], 3=>[], :cat=>[]}`).  That could be a rather nasty bug.  In this situaton, you'd need to use `if my_hash.has_key?(:cat)...` instead.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, you are absolutely right! `Hash#has_key?` is the nice way to check if hash has any particular key or not.